# PHP exec not working properly

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec, wamp

I'm trying to run ffmpeg in my WAMP server with the exec command. Though I have set in the .htaccess file "php_value safe_mode off" and apache allow the override, the exec is still not working properly. if I try to execute

```
   <?
   php exec("mkdir aaa");  
   ?>
```

it works, but when I do something like

```
    exec("ffmpeg.exe -y -i D:\Documents\Video.wmv -f mp4  D:\Documents\Video.mp4 -y");
```

it doesn't do nothing. This works fine is prompted in the command line, but for some reason it doesn't when I try to execute it from the server.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is `ffmpeg.exe` in the `PATH` evn variable for the shell run under Apache? (Check environment with phpinfo.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape backslashes in string literals:

```
exec("ffmpeg.exe -y -i D:\\Documents\\Video.wmv -f mp4  D:\\Documents\\Video.mp4 -y");
```

Comment: Sucks that this has to be done manually, seems like escapeshellarg() should handle escaping backslashes.